# How to get NCover from TestDriven.NET to generate code coverage via the command line

Tags: mstest, ncover

I have VS 2010 Premium SP1 and using MSTest
The project has a web reference to a Web Service
The tests are integration tests
TestDriven.NET-3.8.2877 RTM which includes NCover 1.5.8

My problem is that it runs the `MSTests` and creates the pass/fail `*.trx` file but will not create a coverage report.  I get the coverage report if I right click and select test with\NCover.  The problem is I want to run in in the command line so I can just make it a task in my continuous integration pipeline.

The error returned is:

> Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established.

I searched for solutions and tried the following:

- Using the //reg in the command line
- Updating the config.exe file to use .NET 4.0
- Forcing the NCover DLL to register

Here is my command line:

```
ncover.console.exe //x mstest_coverage.nccov "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:D:\Perforce3666\serviceengine\SessionStorage\dev\SQATesting\SessionStorage.SQA.Testing\bin\Release\SessionStorage.SQA.Testing.dll
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  I tried the 'regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\NCover\CoverLib.dll"' and even the '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\CorFlags.exe" /32BIT+ "C:\Program Files (x86)\nCover\NCover.Console.exe"' command I found.  And I used the //reg.  :<